# How do I get Firebase Phone Authentication to work for my app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've searched on Stack Overflow and read articles and watched videos but still no solution.

Basically I want to send a SMS message by Firebase to user's phone to verify the phone number. My app is not in the Play Store or anything like that, I'm just running it by connecting my phone to PC with a USB cable.

As far as I know I have set it up correctly. This is what I see in Android Studio:

[image]

And in FireBase:
[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    EditText editTextPhone, editTextCode;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    String codeSent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editTextCode = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
        editTextPhone = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonGetVerificationCode).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendVerificationCode();
            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                verifySignInCode();
            }
        });
    }

    private void verifySignInCode(){
        String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //here you can open new activity
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Incorrect Verification Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(){

        String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();

        if(phone.isEmpty()){
            editTextPhone.setError("Phone number is required");
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(phone.length() < 10 ){
            editTextPhone.setError("Please enter a valid phone");
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("code should be sent");

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phone,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }



    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            codeSent = s;
        }
    };


}
```

When I click the Get Verification Button I see the `System.out.println` in the log, "code should be sent" so button is working ok, just no code gets sent. Any ideas please?

Also, I believe I have set up my SHA-1 correctly. I got it from Android Studio by clicking "signingReport" from the Gradle tab and copying the number into Firebase Console, as below.

[image]

Comment: May be because of DND service, not sure. Try it with other number also. And try to print some log in `onVerificationFailed()` and `onCodeSent()`

Comment: @CHarris, have you set your app's SHA-1 hash in firebase console ?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Have tried different phones, doesn't work.

Comment: @NiravBhavsar I did set up the SHA-1 originally, wasn't working, but then I deleted that project as was not certain it was set up properly, started a new Firebase project, and this time did not set up the SHA-1 as I really wanted to start with bare basics and eliminate what could be the problem 1 by 1. SHA-1 necessary, even if not on Play Store?

Comment: @CHarris, yes SHA-1 is necessary, when you run in both debug mode and release mode.

Comment: @NiravBhavsar will have a look now then and report back...

Comment: @NiravBhavsar Still not working, have edited my question to include SHA-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was based on this video and I copied and pasted source code from the github account recommended:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6HBStmDkMQ

Everything looked good in my Firebase console, and the sourcecode was loading and working with no errors - working apart from the SMS being sent I mean - so I copied and pasted the code from this project instead, without needing to change any FireBase settings:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-phone-authentication-android-tutorial/

Now it is sending SMS messages.

Answer (score 1):

Pass number with country code, for ex +91-(10 digit number)

Comment: Thanks but I'm doing that already - putting country code before mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

Here everything looks good.
I think what's going wrong is the mobile input field i.e editTextPhone, because firebase uses the format of

[country-code 10-digit-mobile-no.]

eg. for India  +91 9090102030

So, you should throw the exception or print it in the log section in the **onVerificationFailed** method.